# current measuring in the pspice

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-measurement, pspice

I am testing my circuit but my result seems to be false, I know something is wrong but I can not find the mistake, any help will be appreciated.

with best regards.

[image: this is my circuit]
[image: as you see in this photo the current on two side of the inductor is different]

Comment: as you see in the second photo the current of two sides of the inductor is different(that should not be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong. Two-pin elements have a defined direction for the current: it enters in the first pin and exits through the second. All the other elements (more than 2 pins) are considered to have the currents going in. Probing for current is done in the same manner: it is considered that the current is going in the pin. In addition, there is a convention for the solver: for all the schematic, the current through the meshes is going from top left, to bottom right.

This is what you see there: current enters in pin 1 and exits through pin 2. The mesh current is going from top left, downwards into the source, and right into the inductor (then downwards through the resistor). Since you are probing at the input of the pin, the probe considers the current going in, but the current is coming out of that pin, as directed by the mesh convention. So, you have a negative sign.

Comment: I can't see a capacitor!

Comment: @LeonHeller Me neither! :-) When I wrote the answer I somehow mixed the visual information from an RL to an LC circuit. Thanks for spotting the error.

Comment: Why would this be the convention? If I hook up a physical current loop or break the circuit and put in two probes, I wouldn't see a negative current unless I intentionally reversed the measuring device, which would seem to be a mistake.

Comment: @topher217 It's a software convention, it has no relation to the physical world. The software needs to have some predefined directions for the matrix solver. But, what no software can do (at least that I know of) is to read minds -- none of them will know which way you (the user) want to consider the current, so they resort to their defaults.

Comment: From what I can tell it has nothing to do with left/right top/bottom or pin numbers.  Try a simple circuit, then select all and do Edit->Mirror->Both; probing the same pin, nothing changes.  Flip just the part around to swap pins 1 and 2; nothing changes.  The convention is actually much simpler: positive readings mean (conventional) current is entering the pin, negative means it's leaving it.